# How to make Torque work on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, torque

I have a single PC with a multicore processor and I'm trying to use Torque on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed `torque-mom`, `torque-server`, `torque-client` and `torque-scheduler` through Synaptic.

I can't make it work. I have changed server name and even IP. I can't find specific instructions which can be correctly applied. The official Torque application is not prepared to work with Ubuntu. I'm really tired handling this. What will make it work?

Answer (score -1):

I share your frustration, as torque could really work (better) on Ubuntu.

Meanwhile, maybe the posts about [Torque server will not initialize correctly [11.10]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1936648&p=11797874#post11797874)  on *UbuntuForums.org* can help you.